# RegExp: symbol + length validation

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to make a pretty lean phone validation - digits, hyphens and spaces, no less than 6 symbols.

`\d+[- ]` does what I want but I want to check the length too. Obviously, `(\d+[- ]){6,15}` doesn't work but I imagine it to be something similar. I'd like to limit the length of the whole string too.

Some things I'd like to be valid:
- 0123456789
- 1-800-555-2468
- 1 234 4567

Comment: So what is the maximum length?

Comment: can you share what sort of phone numbers will be valid?

Comment: Lots of people would ask: why not use `str.length >= 6`?

Comment: [\d\- ]{6,} matches a string of at least 6 characters, from a set of digits, hyphens and spaces  I don't think it would be a solution to your problem though.  Can you post example types of phone numbers to validate?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I was wondering if I could do it with regex only. To the other guys, I've added examples.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Still, your question is not clear: do you want to limit the whole string, or the number of digits only.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I've clarified the question. Still, it was about regular expressions, not about phone validation, shouldn't be a duplicate.

Comment: @VergilPenkov You do not have to re-invent a wheel. Use `^(?=.{6,})\d+(?:[ -]\d+)*$` or something like that.

Comment: @Vergil Penkov (?=(\d+([ -]{1}\d+)*)$)(?:.{6,})